Problem with GitHub Pages and React-Router
I have just published my website made with react and I use react-router aswell. Now almost everything works how I like it to be:

When I click a link that leads outside the page, and try to return, it just gives me a 404 error, even though it works when I navigate between pages inside the page.

What could be the issue? What could I do about this? Thanks for the help in advance!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
